# WCF exception - Fault occurred while processing the request.

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I am trying to access data via web service. My webservice calls works perfectly fine but sometimes it throws Fault occurred while processing the request.  `See fault detail for additional information exception`

Here is my stacktrace of the error:

```
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

I have tried increasing the readerQuotas inside my binding. Here is how my bindings looks

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWS" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
           maxDepth="2147483647"
           maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647"
           maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
           maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxx.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWS"
        contract="ABC.IWS" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWS" />
    </client>
```

Am I missing some configuration here ?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. I suspect there is some issue de-serializing the response but at this stake I have no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution is to set all parameter(s) of the service being called. With SOAPUI app you might NOT notice it once. But as always, fiddler says the truth. For example, at first you think that "**important_parameters**" are enough to set for calling the service. And you think web-service considers(/sets itself) "**EndTo**" parameter is 0... Wrong! You ought to set it deliberately, otherwise you get the error mentioned in this post.

```
...
<important_parameters>
   ....
</important_parameters>
<Paging>
   <EndTo>0</EndTo>
</Paging>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the first troubleshooting step was to get more information on the error.  Because of the way Task responses work, there can be many inner exceptions.  So change the handling code to log the inner exceptions.

```
var responseTask = client.someRemoteCall(request);

responseTask.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    switch (t.Status)
    {
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            foreach (var exception in t.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
            {
                log.Error(exception.Message);

                if (exception.InnerException != null)
                {
                    log.Error(exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            {your success code}
        default:
            {some deafult error is thrown}
    }
});
```